# Return an array of functions from map method without execution

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My goal is to generate an array of Promises dynamically (by using Array.map()), and execute them at a posterior time.

```
export const ExecuteReader = async () => {
    let strAll = [1, 2].map((num) => testingFunction (num))
    //await Promise.all(strAll)

}

    export const testingFunction = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('I have been called');
            resolve(1)
        }, 1000)

    })
}
```

ExecuteReader function is called by a "OnPress" event. (React-Native Touchable opacity.)

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={async () => {
            await ExecuteReader().catch(err => console.log(err));
        }}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

To my understanding, the strAll Promise array should not execute its underlying functions, until it has been awaited ("Promise.All")
Im my case, it seems that the "testingFunction" prints out to console, while the "map" is iterating.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: _"My Business logic involves API calls, consequently I will not be able to provide a running example"_ - So instead of building a [mcve] with some dummy data you expect us to do that?

Comment: I have provided a running example that depicts my issue

Answer (score 2):

> To my understanding, the strAll Promise array should not execute its underlying functions, until it has been awaited ("Promise.All") Im my case, it seems that the "testingFunction" prints out to console, while the "map" is iterating.

This is incorrect. The Promise itself will be unfulfilled until the underlying function resolves, but execution begins immediately. You can see this with a simple example (as you've already observed):

```js
const p = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('Underlying function is running.');
  setTimeout(() => resolve('banana'), 500);
});

p.then(console.log);
```

Note that you can await the same promise multiple times. If it's already resolved you'll get the value immediately:

```js
const p = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('Underlying function is running.');
  setTimeout(() => resolve('banana'), 500);
});

p.then(console.log); // takes ~0.5 second
p.then(console.log); // already resolved; logs instantly
p.then(console.log); // instant
p.then(console.log); // instant
p.then(console.log); // instant
```

If you want to defer execution of the underlying function you'd need to defer creation of the promise. It's still not entirely clear to me why you'd need to do this, but you could. Here's a contrived example that just wraps a given function in a "task" object that can be invoked later by calling `task.run()`:

```js
// just wraps the underlying function in
// an object with a 'run' method
function createTask(fn) {
  return {
    run: () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(fn()))
  };
}

// create some tasks that just return the input value
const tasks = [1,2,3].map(v => createTask(() => v));

// nothing's running yet
console.log('not running yet');

// not running until you invoke run()
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('kicking off now');
  Promise.all(tasks.map(t => t.run()))
    .then(console.log);
}, 2000);
```

---

(Original answer)

You just need to return a function that calls your function:

```js
let result = arr.map((element) => () => doubleN(element))
```

Comment: doubleN is a promise. should the map function in this case return another Promise ? My goal is to store all the calls in an array, and then await Promise.all(myArray)

Comment: It's not a Promise until you invoke it. If you want the `Promise.all` you could leave it the way you had it. Or if you wanted to defer it for some reason you could map again and invoke them: `Promise.all(result.map(fn => fn()))`. Not sure what the point of that would be, but you might have your reasons.

Comment: I have amended my question with a relevant example.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the function without calling it, like this :

```
let result = arr.map((element)=> doubleN.bind(this,element))
```

Comment: I have amended my question with a relevant example.